# Why i'm unable to autherize in my django app?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, postman

i'm testing my api. if the user is authenticated then he can able to see the projects otherwise return not authorizated response. I'm passing my jwt token in header but still unable to autherize...?
[image]

```
class ListProjectAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    """This endpoint list all of the available Projects from the database"""
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    queryset = Project.objects.get_all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProjectSerializer
```

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Authorization' tab in postman?

Comment: Yes i tried that too.

Comment: Did you also select the type "Bearer Token"? And if you've selected that option did you remove "Bearer " from the start of the access token?

Comment: Yes both things done but still its behaving like this

Comment: which authentication methods have you configured in the settings?